# Ignoring not set primitive type while converting an object to json using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class which looks like below:-

```
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class JsonPojo {
    private int intVal;
    private String strVal;

    public int getIntVal() {
    return intVal;
    }

    public void setIntVal(int intVal) {
    this.intVal = intVal;
    }

    public String getStrVal() {
    return strVal;
    }

    public void setStrVal(String strVal) {
    this.strVal = strVal;
    }
}
```

If I am having an instance of JsonPojo in which the int field is not set then while converting it to json jackson is assigning it a default 0 as shown below:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonPojo jsonPojo = new JsonPojo();
    jsonPojo.setStrVal("Hello World");
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonPojo);
        System.out.println(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

 }
```

This will output:- `{"intVal":0,"strVal":"Hello World"}`

Is there a way I can ignore `intVal` in Json output when `intVal` is not set without converting the datatype of `intVal` to `Integer`? If I convert `intVal` to Integer then when this value is not set it will be null & doing `JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)` will skip `intVal` during the conversion to json.

But I want to know if it is possible to achieve the same behavior without converting `intVal` to `Integer` from `int`?

I am using jackson 1.9.

Comment: your question is interesting.  I applied a Jsonfilter to the writer, hope this can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try `@JsonInclude` and `@JsonProperty` annotations from [jackson.annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) package. Here's the sample code :

JsonPojo class:

```
public class JsonPojo {
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
private int intVal;
@JsonProperty
private String strVal;

public int getIntVal() {
    return intVal;
}

public void setIntVal(int intVal) {
    this.intVal = intVal;
}

public String getStrVal() {
    return strVal;
}

public void setStrVal(String strVal) {
    this.strVal = strVal;
}}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Actually what I meant was if the `intVal` is not set then only ignore if it set then include it in the json output.

Comment: @tuk in that case you can use `@JsonInclude` tag with the necessary flag. I would suggest that you change the type of `intVal` to `Integer` and set it to `null` initially so that you can use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`. You can use the old one as i showed in the answer but the problem with using `Include.NON_DEFAULT` is that if you set `intVal` to 0 it still will ignore it since the default value for `int` is 0.

Answer (score 7):

`Inclusion.NON_EMPTY` should do what you expect. From the documentation:

> Value that indicates that only properties that have values that values
>   that are null or what is considered empty are not to be included.

Java primitive `int` is by default 0 (this is considered empty). So if you never set it or you set it to 0 the output should be `{"strVal":"Hello World"}` I tried this on jackson 2.6.3 and seems to work so I assume there is an issue on 1.9

You could try the following and maybe works on 1.9:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
private int intVal;
```

and remove `include = Inclusion.NON_EMPTY`

If 0 is a valid value you could add a flag to your pojo. In you ever call the setter the flag should turn to true:

```
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean set = false;

    public Integer getIntVal() {
        if (!set) {
            return null;
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(intVal);
    }

    public void setIntVal(int intVal) {
        set = true;
        this.intVal = intVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if this is an acceptable solution:

We can apply a custom filter to check whether `intVal` is set:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonFilter("theFilter")
public class JsonPojo {
    private int intVal;
    private String strVal;

    private boolean isSetIntVal = false;

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean getIsSetIntVal() {
        return isSetIntVal;
    }

    public int getIntVal() {
        return intVal;
    }

    public void setIntVal(int intVal) {
        this.intVal = intVal;
        this.isSetintVal = true;
    }

    public String getStrVal() {
        return strVal;
    }

    public void setStrVal(String strVal) {
        this.strVal = strVal;
    }
}
```

Implement a custom filter and then apply to the writer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter theFilter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
        @Override
        public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider,
                BeanPropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {

            if (!writer.getName().equals("intVal")) {
                writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                return;
            }
            if (((JsonPojo) pojo).getIsSetIntVal()) {
                writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
            }

        }

    };

    JsonPojo jsonPojo = new JsonPojo();
    jsonPojo.setStrVal("Hello World");
    jsonPojo.setIntVal(0);
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("theFilter", theFilter);
        mapper.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        String json = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(jsonPojo);
        System.out.println(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Actually what I meant was if the intVal is not set then only ignore if it set then include it in the json output.